# retrieve registered token from firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I understand that client app send request for registration and firebase return with some token which we need to store on our app server so that later can be used for sending notification to particular device. I want to know is there any way to get the same token on firebase server using it's console?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Firebase console has no feature to show what FCM Instance ID tokens have been handed out. If you want to have  listing of all the tokens in your app, you will have to store it yourself.